# Grid system in bootstrap doesn't work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div with the `row` class, inside this div I have two nested divs, one with `col-md-3` and the other with `col-md-9`.

So the div with the `row` class takes the whole space as expected :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But the problem is in the div with `col-md-9` it doesn't take the space that it should take, as you can see in this picture :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

So why I'm getting this behaviour ?

PS : for the `contenu-central` class it has only a `padding-left: 0px;`
 and a `padding-right: 0px;`

Comment: There is no `col-md-3` in your code. You are also applying a fixed width to your sidebar `width: 190px;` which will completely break the bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a few things wrong.

- Make sure other aspects of bootstrap are working
- It looks like you have a col-md-9 and a col-md-2, I don't see a 3
- Double check your CSS and make sure there isn't anything limiting the size and overwriting the bootstrap CSS

Comment: Yeah sorry, for the `col-md-2` I just forgot and posted the old code, anyway I updated my question, for the boostrap css rules for the `row` and `col-md-9` they are not ovverited by other css rules as you can see in this picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDtN0.png, and this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw62m.png

Comment: It's the fixed width that's messing up the grid system.

Comment: yes I noticed that, I don't know how I missed it, so anyway it works when I used `col-md-2` and `col-md-10`, thanks